# Java AWT in Windows CE doesn't recognize Key pressed or Key down event

Tags: java, awt, windows-ce

I'm trying to get a "key down" or "key pressed" event inside an AWT interface that runs on a Windows CE device, it recognize only the key released event. (I can't use swing because the jvm doesn't support swing and runs Java 1.4)

```
public class MyView extends Panel implements AWTEventListener
{
    public MyView() {
            super();
        this.requestFocus();
            this.getToolkit().addAWTEventListener(this, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    }
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Event ID: "+event.getID());
    }
}
```

(I also tried with a KeyListener)

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular `KeyListener`

```
public MyView() {
    super();
    this.requestFocus();
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getKeyChar() + " Typed");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getKeyChar() + " Released");

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getKeyChar() + " Pressed");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I've also tried with a keyListener but both of them only recognize keyReleased :'(